# integrate magento site with all popular sites

Tags: extensions, websites

we are devoloping magento site.

so we are planning to integrate our magento sites with other popular

sites like :amazon, snapdeal, flipkart...etc.

purpose:

assume we have 10 products for name "product 1".

if customer bought our product from amazon.com , the inventory should automatically

reduce to 9 in all other sites.

using magento REST & SOAP API, how to sell our products in other sites?

please guide me about this.

thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: How did you resolve this?? Can you please share the details?

Comment: you can try with `unicommerce` once http://www.unicommerce.com/ @Bilal

Comment: Uniware provide magento integration in paid version,,,In free or LITE version uniware do not provide Magento integration.

Is there any alternatives??

Comment: @Bilal yes, thats paid, sorry i don't know any other solution....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento have it own Api feature [Rest and Soap Api.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)

Using this you can fill your requirement.

From admin create [api user](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magebridge/administration/596-step-by-step-create-a-magento-api-user) and create user for each site.

Using magento api you can magento stock and product ,sales etc.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: hi amit,

thanks a lot for reply.

for an example, if we want to sell our products by flipkart.com,

what and all information we have to take flipkart.com .

anything like API key or any username, password..?...

Comment: Can you please tell me onething .is filpkart provide api key?

Comment: yes, Flipkart provide api key...